# How to make multiple requests and save the data objects into a new array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have two methods, which make a GET request. The first method saves user objects into the Benutzer array and in the benutzerIDs array only the user ids are saved. In the second method I'd like to loop through the benutzerIDs array and use these IDs for another GET Request and save the Objects into the array test. I have a problem with executing this request because of the multiple IDs. Currently I can't save the data into test. How can I loop throught the benutzerIDs and make a request based on this IDs?

```
getBenutzerDesVorgesetzten(id) {
  axios
    .get(server.baseURL + "/benutzer/vorgesetzter/" + id)
    .then(response => {
      this.benutzerIDs = [];
      this.Benutzer = response.data;
      this.Benutzer.forEach((item) => {
        this.benutzerIDs.push(item.BenutzerID);
      });
    });
    this.getAnträgeByBenutzerID();
},
getAnträgeByBenutzerID(){
  this.test = [];
  this.benutzerIDs.forEach((id) =>
     this.test = axios.all([axios.get(server.baseURL + "/urlaubsantrag/benutzer/" + id)]))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
getAnträgeByBenutzerID(){
    this.test = [];
    const promises = [];
    this.benutzerIDs.forEach(id => {
        promises.push(axios.get(server.baseURL + "/urlaubsantrag/benutzer/" + id))
    })

    axios
        .all(promises)
        .then(res =>
            //res is an array of raw data
            this.test = res.map(item => item.data);
         )
}
```

Comment: It works partly.. I can't get the res.data and can only store the whole response into the test array.

Comment: If you want to get data, you have to run map, then query the data inside the callback function. I have editted my answer to make it clearer

Comment: Okay this works, but I don't understand why I have an array (of objects) in an array, that seems not right for me.

Comment: so in general, the response you get from `axios.get()` is a single object which you normally go like: `response.data` to get the data. However with `axios.all()`, it will return an array of responses, so you have to loop through the array (`res` in this case), get data from each one of them (`item.data`)

Comment: Does this clear up your confusion? Please mark this as an accepted answer if you feel so.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `Promise.all` and `Array.prototype.map`:

```js
getAnträgeByBenutzerID(){
  return Promise.all(this.benutzerIDs.map((id) =>
     axios.get(server.baseURL + "/urlaubsantrag/benutzer/" + id)])));
}
```

The map callback creates an array of promises which are then collectively returned once they are all resolved.

Comment: And how can i store the data objects into an array?